# gif not animating correctly in Microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, animated-gif

I am working with a loading gif on a website and it works correctly on all browsers except Microsoft edge. With edge, the gif runs all the way through the loading circle, but at what I assume is the last frame*, a sliver of the gif freezes and stays there as the gif continues to play through again. Once it happens one time, it will continue to happen until the user leaves the page. I can't put up a link to show the actual gif I am struggling with,
however I just created something quickly in paint.net and threw it into an online animation tool to show what it is doing.

https://giphy.com/gifs/QsUAu5ud4ibIdq97sm

So with this quick gif I just created, once that red mark shows up, it will show up every time after the initial load of the gif.

*I am just assuming it is the last frame but I can not access a copy of the gif before it was compiled into gif format so I don't know how much of the loading animation is in each frame

What I am asking is if anyone knows how to fix this issue when using edge. I am limited because I cannot change the gif itself in anyway or change
the frame rate of the gif. Any ideas are welcome because I am all out of ideas and have spent hours scrolling through
pages online looking for a solution and haven't come across anything close to what is happening here.

Also this is how the gif is being created on the page with the html. Not sure if this is helpful in this case or not:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="~/Content/images/GIF-loading.gif" id="loadingGif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Which kind of Edge browser version are you using? Can you share the GIF-loading.gif, so that we could test it on our side.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0. Sadly, I cannot share the loading.gif, which  I know only makes this harder to help with. Also I do know older versions also had this issue as well. I am looking currently to find something I can post freely online that has the same issue. The best I can do is show what is going on - which is the link above - and hope someone might have an idea to try from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to create a sample using your code and download a loading image from [here](https://icons8.com/preloaders/), it seems that it works well on Microsoft Edge 44 and Edge 42, the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw5wA.gif). So, I think you could try to download a new loading image and retest it on your side.

Comment: At this point, I believe this would be the only option to fix this issue. However, I can't easily get another copy of the gif with slight changes to it (From a lot of online searching, I believe a setting (FPS) might need to be changed when it's being put into gif format. Since I don't have access to this, it's not something I can do.) If I ever get a hold of a new copy of the gif I'll post if that fixed it. Thanks for the help though!